# How to cut and export audio in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio

BH

All I'm trying to do is create a basic Audio Editor in the browser, no server, which allows the user to select in and out times for various input audio clips, imported in the "bin", and decide when they should end, and make cuts the the middle etc. and place them together, and finally, export it all

I could just record through all of the cut audio using the MediaRecorder API, stopping and starting at each cut point etc., but that would take a lot of time, when using Premeire for example, its usually able to export a very long audio-edit sequence in a few seconds, I would like to get something like this in browser-JavaScript, but I don't know how to?

I've seen  [mp3-cuter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp3-cutter) but that's only for NodeJS, is there anything similar for Browser-JavaScript?

Obviously there's webpack for nodejs as well, but it's complicated to manage, especially with file writing etc

Comment: Have you looked into the Web Audio API? I think you need to look into converting your audio files into PCM data, editing that, and converting the PCM back to audio files.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner interesting Ive looked into the web audio API in general but I didnt know it allowed for audio splitting, is there a specific reference for converting audio to PCM , editing that and back? I couldnt find it on the standard mozilla docs

Comment: IDK the API that well, but I once used it in a Spring project: generated PCM via Java at the server. Then, with thymeleaf, handed the raw PCM data array to Javascript in browser. Using the Web Audio API, played the PCM array directly from the data array. Timing is calculated by counting the number of data points and multiplying by the sample rate. Example: at 44100 fps (mono), 1/2 second is 22050 frames (PCM values). You might ask elsewhere about specifics of Web Audio API. No "splitter" afaik--you'd have to do it by splitting the arrays. I used AudioBuffer to hold the PCM.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner interesting so no splitting bult in, but it does allow one to split it exactly at the right time, and the two split parts will fit together? wont it corrupt the file?

Comment: If you take two segments of PCM and concatenate them, the connection point will likely be a signal discontinuity and produce a click. One way to deal is to connect silence to silence. Another is to overlap the two, and use linear interpolation between the two to transition from one to the other (sometimes called an AB roll or cross-fade).

Comment: @PhilFreihofner hi thanks ive been trying this, but now i'm having trouble getting the data back to the webm format that it came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609193/encode-wav-or-raw-pcm-data-to-webm-in-javascript any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community hi there's no code to provide that's relevant here, as the question explains, its asking for general methods...