# Encode WAV [or raw PCM data] to WebM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio, vorbis

BH

I'm trying to make a basic audio editor / cutter and exporter with native JavaScript, so far I have been able to read the raw PCM data of input audio files using `AudioContext.deocdeAudio`, as well as export as a WAV, but I want to compress it, since a two minute video is around 10mb...

I've been trying to cexport to mp3 using lamejs, but th emscripten version is very slow, and plus there are many copyright issues with mp3, so I want to export it as a webm audio, and / or add it to a webm video. [If a webm video is written with only audio, it plays as audio in the browser anyways, so I can deal with that].

Problem is, is that outside of the `MediaRecorder` [which is unreliable with exact timing] I haven't been able to find any JavaScript solutions that write a WebM *audio* file directly [although I was able to find some [WebM video writer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)s in pure JavaScript]

I have found vorbis which seems to be able to encode audio with a WebM container, but I haven't found any native JavaScript versions of it

I would use [webm-muxer.js](https://github.com/davedoesdev/webm-muxer.js) but its not supported on my chromebook, and want to use a way thats more widely supported

Comment: AFAIK, the Fraunhofer copyright on mp3 format expired in 2017, and is no longer an issue.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner interesting, so MP3 is completely open source now? DO u know of any native javascript MP3 encoders? the lame.js one didn't seem to work for me

Comment: Sorry, all I've done with JavaScript (Web Audio API) is playback PCM data. All my processing experience is with Java. Maybe one of these is helpful? https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/audio-processing/javascript